# Express.js keeps returning old query results that no longer exist in the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I am using PostgreSQL with Express.js

I came across a problem, that when I update my database, with new entries, and delete old ones, no matter what, it keeps returning only the old ones (that were deleted several days ago already), as if it was using cache.

I tried:

Setting headers -         `res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private');`

Restarting the database itself, and using `VACUUM ANALYZE` on PostgreSQL;

This is my connection to the database:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const { dbConfig, sshConfig } = require('./database_config');

const dbPool = new Pool(dbConfig);

const connectToDatabase = () => {
    dbPool.connect((error) => {
        if (error) throw error;
    });
};

module.exports = { dbPool, connectToDatabase };
```

This is one of my endpoints.

```
//I connect to the database in index.js
connectToDatabase();


app.get('/getEntries', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const query = 'SELECT * FROM listings';

        const result = await dbPool.query(query);
        res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private');

        res.json(result.rows);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Error fetching data');
    }
});
```

It keeps returning old data, deleted a while ago from the Database, how to address this issue?

Comment: You may want to verify if you are connecting and working (deleting and querying) with the same database all the time.

Comment: @prasad_ I am indeed connecting to that database, checked the connection via a terminal, with the same credentials, the database queries new results, while the backend returns old ones. There are also no other existing databases rather than the initial one.

Comment: Do you log requests in Express, for example using Morgan? Do you see requests actually getting handled by your Express server?

Comment: Does the problem go away if you restart pgsql? Does the problem go away if you restart your app? If you query the pgsql database directly, do you still see the deleted rows?

Comment: @rveerd No I do not log yet, the Express app is barebones, at the beggining stage of development.

Comment: @SalmanA No it does not go away if I restart psql. No it does not go away if I restart my app. If I query directly, only new results are there, old rows are nowhere to be found.

Comment: @dovexz12323  Can you post the rest of the middleware you are using with express?

Comment: @dovexz12323 Do you get old data returned from api itself or from db? And what is the client? You check in browser or making api request from server also yields same old data?

Comment: can you post the code in ./database_config ?

Comment: How are you making the requests to the server? Perhaps the client is caching the results and therefore not actually calling the api... @dovexz12323 That seems to be the likely culprit. And based on your remarks to rveerd you will definitely want to do some logging (especially if you are at the beginning stages of development). Even simple logs to define what middleware you are engaging can save you a lot of time when debugging.

Comment: Try to close the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In plain database context, this sort of thing would happen if either your bulk DML (`insert`, `update`, `delete`, `truncate`, `merge` you meant by *"when I update my database"*) was executed but never committed, or the clients in your pool had their autocommit off/are operating in transactions, unintendedly. My bet is on the former: your separate, external process of applying the bulk change wasn't followed by a `commit`. If you did that manually from a db client and verified your changes were applied by subsequently running some `select` statements after that bulk DML, the `select` would've shown they are indeed visible, but that's because changes resulting from previous statements are immediately visible *within the same transaction*.
2. It could be confused identifiers: if multiple parts of your system address the same `listings` table using different capitalisation and quoting rules, you might end up with multiple different tables. `Listings`, `LISTINGS`, `LiStInGs` and `listings` are all folded to lowercase `listings`, unless you or something processing your query wraps the identifier in double quotes - then it's treated verbatim, and accessible only using the double-quoted name: [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

   > Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case.

   you can check `information_schema.tables` to see if that's not the case

   ```
   select table_schema,table_name 
   from information_schema.tables 
   where table_name ilike '%listings%';
   ```
3. You could've also created alternate versions of you `listings` table in different [namespaces/schemas](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH). It's especially likely if there are schemas named after users (those by default precede other schemas) and your clients operate under a different user than your big DML did. Query from point 2. should detect that as well.
4. If you're re-using usernames, db names and passwords between environments and you have a lot running on the same network/machine it's possible your clients are connecting somewhere else than where you end up "via terminal". You can thoroughly examine if connection params match fully, see what's running where, on what port. You can create a unique table through one channel and see if it's visible via another. If not, they might be connecting different places and/or there's transaction isolation and you're forgetting to run `commit`.
5. It's possible to quietly alter visibility using [row-level security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) or the [rule system](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-views.html). The former acts as if there were additional, invisible conditions added to all your queries, the latter can completely re-direct your queries.
6. `express.js` uses `node-postgres` to talk to the db, so there's no way around autocommit except explicitly issuing a `BEGIN` statement. It's very unlikely but technically possible to poison your pool if you attempted to use [`repeatable read` or `serializable` transaction isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-REPEATABLE-READ) in [`pool.query()`](https://node-postgres.com/features/transactions): this would randomly and quietly result in clients being released back into the pool with an open transaction, holding on to an old snapshot of the db. Each client would then be doomed to continue its life in its own, parallel universe, where all other life ceased to exist and only their own actions do anything, until they happen to `commit` or `rollback`. That's a big *if*, assuming clients don't automatically attempt a commit upon release back to the pool.